# Stripping whitespace in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am interested in removing leading/trailing whitespace in a .csv file, and I was wondering if there's a better way to execute this:

```
with open("csv_file.csv", "rb") as infile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    fieldnames = r.fieldnames #Creates list of fieldnames

    for row in r:
        for f in fieldnames:
            row[f] = row[f].strip()
```

I am fine with using this method, but I was wondering if there's a way to circumvent using a nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need the `b` flag when opening a csv file.
Python 3 doesn't let me use it. I think you can drop it.

To eliminate one level of nesting,
you can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), and the `update` method of a dictionary:

```
with open("/path/to/file.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames

    for row in reader:
        row.update({fieldname: value.strip() for (fieldname, value) in row.items()})
```

Notice that I also renamed the variables, as they were very poorly named.
I also removed the "r" flag from the `open`, as that's the default mode anyway.

I don't think there's a simpler way to do this.
I tried using a [dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params), but this is the best I could get:

```
with open("/path/to/file.csv") as infile:
    csv.register_dialect('strip', skipinitialspace=True)
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, dialect='strip')
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Which does NOT work as intended: whitespace is stripped from the left of each field, but not from the right.
My first thought was actually to set `delimiter=r'\s*,\s*'` when registering the dialect,
but that doesn't work because `delimiter` must be a single character,
it cannot be a regex.
So, if you want to strip spaces from the values,
you have no choice but do it yourself.